# How to read call log in xamarin.ios?

Tags: xamarin.forms, callkit

I just want to know if is possible to read recent calls in iOS, if this is true, please give me suggestions.

Comment: Here is the apple document about all calling function. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit Unfortunately, if want to log , this need yourself to storage when incoming or outgoing call .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  iOS does not expose any API to do this.  It would be a privacy nightmare.

Comment: Suggestive comment is useless.